# Command line utility for reading tabular data

Tags: software-rec, text

I am looking for a command line utility that would allow me to quickly investigate structure of a large dataset. Right now I am doing it by using: `head -n 2 dataset` but the problem is that the width of the output is larger than width of my terminal/screen.

What would be perfect is a tool to horizontally scroll through the file (by a fixed number of columns), the same way I can scroll through file opened in Vim by using `Ctrl+f`/`Ctrl+b`.

Comment: Why not [Vim](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/scroll.html#scroll-horizontal)?

Comment: @Gilles, because of the large (few GBs) size, which from my experience Vim cannot handle very well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend `less`

You can browse in any direction With

```
less -S logfile
```

> **-S** or **--chop-long-lines**
>
> ```
>           Causes lines longer than the screen width to be chopped rather than folded.  That is, the portion of a long line that does not fit in the screen width is not shown.  The default is to fold long lines; that is, display
>           the remainder on the next line.
> ```

For horizontal movement

> **ESC-)** or **RIGHTARROW**
>
> ```
>           Scroll horizontally right N characters, default half the screen width (see the -# option).  If a number N is specified, it becomes the default for future RIGHTARROW and LEFTARROW commands.  While the text is scrolled,
>           it acts as though the -S option (chop lines) were in effect.
> ```
>
> **ESC-(** or **LEFTARROW**
>
> ```
>           Scroll horizontally left N characters, default half the screen width (see the -# option).  If a number N is specified, it becomes the default for future RIGHTARROW and LEFTARROW commands.
> ```

Comment: You can also type `-S` from within `less`

Comment: See also the `most` pager that doesn't wrap by default.